# Outlook search does not appear an email when I cut a letter

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

First i want to say that I am new to StackExchange and this is my first question. I have a problem with outlook search. I check on the StackExchange and I couldn't find any answers. I have received an email from a user aageli@contoso.gr. When I search aageli to outlook email appears on the results when I cut the first letter and search for ageli email does not appear.
I try to troubleshoot the problem. First I rebuild index, I check indexed locations, forwarded the email to a different client (same problem as well), Trying to search the email throw outlook.office365.com.
On the company we are using Office 365 pro plus with an exchange mailbox. Its important to be able to look something like that because ageli is a last name in Greece. This not happens only to one email address, for example if I have received an email from mklouvatos@contoso.gr and try to search by last name klouvatos I am not able to find this email but if I search form mklouvatos email appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Outlook Advanced search for such options,
but it's not easy to find or to use:

- Click in the Search pane
  (if it is not shown, click once in the Search box)
- Click on *Search Tools > Advanced Find*
- Go to the Advanced tab
- Select a field, ensure that the condition is "contains" and enter your string
- Continue if more fields are required
- Click "Find Now" to search.

(I agree that this procedure is atrociously complex, which is one of the
reasons that I don't use Outlook.)

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Outlook uses what's called prefix matching when searching. It's by design and i think this is to avoid searching for other items that contain this field.

[image]

For more information about search feature, please refer to: [How to search in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-search-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da#:%7E:text=Note%3A%C2%A0Outlook%20uses,that%20contain%20%22Microsoft365%22.).

By the way, For the advanced search mentioned by harrymc, I don't think such a search will be very accurate. I'm afraid you need to enter complete fields to get accurate search results.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.